# NSURL for phone number returns nil

Tags: swift, nsurl

So I am trying to trigger a phone call from within my app and I've got the following piece of code to do so.

```
    let phoneNumber = personEntitity.primaryContactNumber?
    if let callUrl = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(callUrl)
    }
```

However, the callUrl is always nil so the openURL call is never called. phoneNumber is a valid string with a phone number such as phoneNumber = "12345678"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm assuming it's something trivial.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you share an example that produces a nil URL? If I try what you've posted, I always get an NSURL, even if `phoneNumber` is an `Optional(None)` or `Optional(12345678)` or `"12345678"` or `12345678`.

Comment: When debugging my particular example, phoneNumber is a (String?) assigned the value "23960285".

Comment: Nevermind. Unwrapping the optional solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was simple.

```
let phoneNumber = personEntitity.primaryContactNumber?
    if let callUrl = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber!)") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(callUrl)
    }
```

Comment: You should just unwrap it with if let to begin with, on the first line. You could even chain the conditions.